# Does a villager have to be 6 blocks below the door to not be counted in the villager cap?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

People say to dig down 6 blocks and have 6 doors on ground level. Does it have to be exactly 6? Can it be more or less?  Is that from the bottom of the door to the block the villagers feet is under? [image]
Also is there anything wrong that would prevent villagers from reproducing in this picture?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height difference has to be 6 or more but cant be more then 32.  I generally do 10 to be safe.  Also, there can be no doors other then on the level with the single villager within 64 blocks.

As to the number of doors, it has to be at least 6.  It can be more if they are placed in the right position, but you don't need anymore then 6 for this to work.  It is a waste of doors.  With 6 doors, they will continue to breed infinitely.

Generally speaking, I have one villager with 6 doors, all by his lonesome.  Then 10 blocks above or below him, I have the villagers that I want to breed.

What is happening is the single villager and his 6 doors create a village that should have 2 villagers.  The villagers above/below him are considered a part of the village which means they are in breed mode, but they are not counting in the village census.  So it is a village with 1 counted villager and other villagers in breed mode which are not counted(and neither are their offspring) so they just continue to breed.  [Here is the wiki on villager breeding](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Breeding) for more info.

Additionally, if you supply the breeding villagers with a farm and have at least one brown coat villager, he will farm and feed the breeders.

---

Here is the simplest "infinite breeder" I could come up with for an example:
[image: Breeder]

Comment: Hearts are popping up quite often, nothing happens though. Does that mean it’s working properly and just needs time?

Comment: If you have hearts, you did it right.  You might try to contain the breeders in a smaller section for a while just to keep them close to each other.  Also, feed them if they need it.  Once it gets going, watch out for entity over load.

Comment: There’s tons of hearts but no babies

Comment: I built it in creative mode and had no problem. But on my survival world, nothing works

Comment: Did you make sure they are well fed?  I generally throw a few stacks of potatoes at them.  The hearts may only be coming from one villager who is willing.

Comment: Yeah I’ve thrown an inventory full of potatoes down there

Comment: Can you upload the world so I can take a look at it?  Or at least post several more pictures in the question.

Comment: I’m on console so I can’t upload it. I’ll put more pictures though.

Comment: It’s up @IronAnvil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71796/discussion-between-ironanvil-and-carter-ray).

Answer (score 0):

The villager has to be outside the village. Internally, the village is a sphere which extends quite a bit more than just all of its houses. So I don't think there's ever a case where 6 blocks are enough.

There are many factors to the size of a village. If you really need to know the minimum distance, you can open a copy of the world with the [village info mod](http://chunkbase.com/mods/village-info) installed. Otherwise, just go a few hundred blocks away, that should always work.

If you have much time, you can also see at which point the villager starts to behave differently. For example villagers try to run to houses at night, but only if they are inside the village range.

Comment: In the context of a villager breeder where the villagers need to be below the village, does it work?

Comment: Why do you even want it below? Why not somewhere else completely?

Comment: They’re below it and think they’re in the village and reproduce while they are actually outside it and cheat the villager mob cap.

Comment: You mean you have a Minecraft world where they are already underneath the village? Well, move them then, if you want them outside.

Comment: I added a picture to hopefully show what I mean.

Comment: That's a test world. You can move the villager wherever you want. And by the breeding particles you can see that they are still inside the village.